# Python pandas creating data frame with variable number of inputs

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to create pandas dataframe with variable number of columns.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
MonthNumber = np.array([1,1,2,4,5,6,5])
Type1 = np.array(['A','B','C',A','A','B','C'])
Type2 = np.array([1,1,0,1,0,0,1])
Data = np.array([1.1,3,.52,34,15,45,34])
Data2 = Data * 1.1
Data3 = Data * 2 

def variableDataFrame(*args):
    df = pd.DataFrame({'MonthNumber':args1, 'Data':args2})
    print df.columns
```

So, the calls to function looks like:

```
variableDataFrame(MonthNumber,Data) #prints MonthNumber,Data
variableDataFrame(MonthNumber,Type1,Data) # prints MonthNumber,Type1,Data
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to complete your code and make it work for what you've provided, I'd do this:

```
def variableDataFrame(*args):
    """I'm assuming the last argument is the data argument.
    Everything else gets put into an index.
    If you want these as columns instead of rows,
    put a ".T" at the end of the return argument."""

    return pd.DataFrame(args[-1], index=pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays(args[:-1]))

    # Optional return if you want columns instead
    # return pd.DataFrame(args[-1], index=pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays(args[:-1])).T
```

## But I will put a large caveat on this!!!

You are creating a replacement for `pd.DataFrame`.  All you've/I've done is reshuffle and obfuscate the arguments.  In order to get it to work, you need to know what goes in what slot which is the same thing you need to know when you use `pd.DataFrame` in the first place.

With that out of my system, I hope that helps.